# having trouble getting devtools::install_github() to work in R on Win 7 64bit machine

Tags: r, devtools

each time I try to run install_github()  from RStudio I get something like this:

```r
devtools::install_github("r-lib/devtools")
```

```
Downloading GitHub repo r-lib/devtools@master
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = download_method(), quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/r-lib/devtools/tarball/master'*
```

I tried the work around described in https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/1772

and this is what I get:

```r
assignInNamespace("version_info", c(devtools::version_info, list("3.5" = list(version_min = "3.3.0", version_max = "99.99.99", path = "bin"))), "devtools")
```

```
Error in bindingIsLocked(x, ns) : no binding for "version_info"
```

```r
find_rtools() # is TRUE now
```

```
Error in find_rtools() : could not find function "find_rtools"*
```

Please suggest a workaround to get `devtools::install_github()` to work on my Win PC.

Comment: Furthermore when I run: _> devtools::find_rtools()_
I get: _Error: 'find_rtools' is not an exported object from 'namespace:devtools'_

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution for this Win 7 64 bit machine which was based on:
https://github.com/r-lib/remotes/issues/130

Click Start > type in "Internet Options" > click "Internet options" > Go to "Advanced" and check TLS 1.2 box.

Answer (score 5):

for me this worked on Windows 10

```
options(download.file.method = "wininet")
```

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206827897-Secure-Package-Downloads-for-R

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 3):

It works for me.
`options(download.file.method = "libcurl")`

Answer (score -1):

use of library(devtools) firsts, followed by install_github("<pkg_name>") works instead of using 1-line command using scope resolution operator (::)