# Problems installing papaja in R version 3.6.1. & R studio version 1.2.5001

Tags: r, devtools, papaja

I have successfully installed Rtools and devtools but am getting an error message when I try to install papaja from github

I have already tried:
1) Reinstalled both R and Rstudio so I have the latest versions. 
2) Googled the error message but no answers. 
3) Downloaded the papaja package from github and tried installing it from my local hard drive 
4) unzipped it and re-zipped it with 7-zip, then tried to install it again from local hard drive

Code used is:

```r
devtools::install_github("crsh/papaja")
```

But installation does not complete. Error message I receive is:

```
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  cannot open URL 'https://api.github.com/repos/crsh/papaja/tarball/master'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [having trouble getting devtools::install\_github() to work in R on Win 7 64bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53845962/having-trouble-getting-devtoolsinstall-github-to-work-in-r-on-win-7-64bit-ma)

Comment: I haven't tried the suggestion because the 2nd attempt at installing it from my hard drive worked!